# New Micro SD write protection not by-passable

Tags: formatting, raspbian, sd-card

I have a brand new sandisk 512gb and 64gb micro sd cards. I have been trying to format them to then upload raspbian on to them for my raspberry pis but both are write protected and I can't clean wither of them manually (by pushing down the tab on the sd card adapter) or virtually through diskpart function on the command line. I get to "**disk attributes cleared successfully**" but then the "**clean**" command fails:

[image: DiskPart has encountered an error: The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error. See the System Event Log for more information.]

```
DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> attributes disk clear readonly

Disk attributes cleared successfully.

DISKPART> clean

DiskPart has encountered an error: The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART>
```